# Verify detached XAdES signature on file

Tags: java, x509certificate, xades4j

I am trying to verify integrity of a file "test.zip" using detached XAdES signature "test.zip.xades" using xades4j library. I am aware that easier way would be using md5, but I need to use XAdES. I don't want to verify CA chain etc, just verify integrity of the file. Is it possible?
I am having following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("verifyDetachedC");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("cacerts");

      KeyStore trustAnchors = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
      trustAnchors.load(fis,"changeit".toCharArray());
      fis.close();

      CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new CertificateValidationProviderImpl();
      XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
      p.acceptUnknownProperties(true);

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
      DocumentBuilder db =  dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      FileInputStream isXades = new FileInputStream("test.zip.xades");
      Document doc = db.parse(isXades);
      Element signatureNode = getSigElement(doc);

      FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.zip");
      SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions options = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions().useDataForAnonymousReference(is);
      XAdESVerificationResult res = verifier.verify(signatureNode, options);
      is.close(); 
    }

class CertificateValidationProviderImpl implements CertificateValidationProvider {
    @Override
    public ValidationData validate(X509CertSelector certSelector,
                                   Date validationDate,         
Collection<X509Certificate> otherCerts)
            throws CertificateValidationException, UnexpectedJCAException {
        return new ValidationData((List<X509Certificate>) otherCerts);
    }
}
```

I am getting "Invalid signature value for signature ID-39XXXX". I am not sure if code is working, but signature is wrong or code is not working.
Signature has Signature Id="ID-39XXXX, Reference URI=test.zip (relative), and ds:X509Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there was a problem with the signature value, but the reference digests are OK.

If you reference has a relative URI it is not an anonymous reference, meaning you don't need `useDataForAnonymousReference(is)`. Other than that, the code seems fine. Are you sure that the original signature is well generated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was wrong. Actually there was absolute relative  URI="file:///path/to/test.zip. Without that I am getting: Could not find a resolver for URI. I can not find example showing how to use it with relative path. Another issue, the code it self is wrong I suppose. I found correct file with xades signature (I modify URI) and still getting "Invalid signature value for signature "